# CryptoJS.HmacSHA512 returns undefined

Tags: javascript, cryptography, hmac, cryptojs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/lib/hmac-sha512.js"></script>
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512('1111111', 'stub11111');
```

CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
But why hash is undefined?

Comment: Did you simply forgot to quote the input and key?

Comment: @Artjom B., sorry, it is a string in my code, not proper cop-paste fixed. Question still exists.

Comment: It's still not reproducible. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably in stacksnippet/jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr.

Comment: Hm, it is strange. code works without changes.

Answer (score 1):

The message must be passed as a string;

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512("1111111", stub11111);
```

(Assuming stub11111 is a variable, otherwise quote it)

Comment: Sorry, it is a string in my code, not proper cop-paste fixed. Question still exists.